# Use host-only network adapter in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm using OSX 10.9.4 as host, VirtualBox 4.3.14 and Windows 7 as the guest VM. Using NAT network mode works fine. But host-only networking never worked. I'm fairly new to using VirtualBox and VM's. Whatever network connection/IP the host has, I want the same thing to be applied to the guest and not as a new computer on the network.

I have proprietary VPN software running on the host when this is enabled only Outlook in the guest works. Not able to open any webpage in the browser while VPN on the host is running and I was thinking host-only mode will help as all the traffic will "flow" from the host to guest allowing me to open webpages on the guest. But host-only doesn't work with or without VPN software installed on the host.

I've done the below, except DHCP is disabled. Enabling it also didn't make any difference.

[image: I've already done this under VirtualBox Preferences.]

ipconfig info from guest -

```
C:\Users\admin>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8cf2:f1a7:c2f7:6ee0%11
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.110.224
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{ECABE27B-3ACE-473D-9283-B207F0482D86}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

C:\Users\admin>
```

Comment: 169.254.*.* is the [link-local address range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). You can't normally communicate outside the LAN with one of them. And like @heavyd says, the host-only network type is a closed LAN connecting the hosts and the guests. Having said that, I've read your question twice and I'm not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Could you try to clarify your actual need?

Answer (score 0):

From the [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes) on networking modes:

> **Host-only networking**
>
> This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of
>   virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network
>   interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback
>   interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among
>   virtual machines and the host.

Note that all interaction is between the host and the guest VMs, not the host's other networks, so you won't be able to access the internet via a host only connection, unless your host is setup to do routing.  Have you tried the NAT mode instead?